# date_diff returns 0 if the difference is over a year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am using this function to get month difference between two dates.

```
$interval = date_diff(date_create('2015-10-08'), date_create('2014-10-10'));
$total_months = $interval->format('%m');
```

**RESULT:** 11 (That's Correct!)

But, When the difference is over a year, then,

```
$interval = date_diff(date_create('2015-11-08'), date_create('2014-10-10'));
$total_months = $interval->format('%m');
```

**RESULT:** 0 (That's Wrong!)

why is it returns 0? Is there any way by which I can get difference between any 2 dates? Thanks!

Comment: It returns 0 because it is returning the number of months between the 2 dates. The previous 12 months have become a year.

Comment: 2015-11-08 -> 2014-10-10 is 12 months, aka 1 year 0 months

Comment: Yes. It's taking difference between only months. But, is there any way to resolve this issue? I need months difference between any dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`2015-11-08 to 2014-10-10` is `12` months become a year. So it returns `0` month. Calculate the number of years from the `$interval` then add `(year * 12)` to the number of months. Example here...

```
$interval = date_diff(date_create('2015-11-08'), date_create('2014-10-10'));
$year = $interval->format('%Y');
echo $total_months = $interval->format('%m') + $year * 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or better:

```
$total_months = $interval->y * 12 + $interval->m;
```

You have years and months as fields, no need to use format to obtain parts as texts for later adding the parts!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky and needs a work round , try the following, that could
be it.

```
$first = new DateTime('2015-11-08',new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$second = new DateTime('2014-10-10',new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$diff = $second->diff($first);

$months = (Int)($diff->days/30); 
echo "The two dates have $months months between them.";
```

Output:The two dates have 13 months between them.